# Intel C++ compiler failing to select template function overload

Tags: c++11, templates, g++, overloading, icc

The following code in C++11 compiles correctly with g++ 6.3.0 and result in the behavior that I consider correct (namely, the first function is picked). However with Intel's C++ compiler (icc 17.0.4) it fails to compile; the compiler indicates that multiple possible function overloads exist.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename R, typename ... Args>
static void f(R(func)(const int&, Args...)) {
        std::cout << "In first version of f" << std::endl;
}

template<typename R, typename ... Args, typename X = typename std::is_void<R>::type>
static void f(R(func)(Args...), X x = X()) {
        std::cout << "In second version of f" << std::endl;
}

double h(const int& x, double y) {
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  f(h);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the error reported by icc:

```
test.cpp(18): error: more than one instance of overloaded function "f" matches the argument list:
            function template "void f(R (*)(const int &, Args...))"
            function template "void f(R (*)(Args...), X)"
            argument types are: (double (const int &, double))
    f(h);
    ^
```

So my two questions are: which compiler is correct with respect to the standard? and how would you modify this code so that it compiles? (note that `f` is a user-facing API and I would like to avoid modifying its prototype).

Note that if I remove `typename X = typename std::is_void<R>::type` and the `X x = X()` argument in the second version of `f`, icc compiles it fine.

Comment: `typename std::is_void<R>::type` is **always** `bool`. Are you sure you didn't mean to use it inside `enable_if`?

Comment: No, `std::is_void<R>::type` is of type `std::integral_constant<bool, value>`. `std::is_void<R>::value_type` is `bool`, and `std::is_void<R>::value` is either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. But my question about using `is_void::value` inside `enable_if_t` stands.

Comment: In the full code, I have `x` passed down to another function that has two overloads, one taking an `std::integral_constant<bool, true>` argument, and one taking an `std::integral_constant<bool, false>` argument. I know it's confusing, since I removed the content of both functions it seems that I'm declaring the typename X for nothing, I just wanted to strip the test case to the minimum reproducing the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Intel Compiler 17.0 Update 4. The behavior of GCC is right in this case. This issue is resolved in Intel Compiler 18.0 Update 4 and above.